# Return to subcategory not in the parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a function in the `functions.php` file, so when the user clicks a button, the user will return to the previous category page of the product that belongs to even if it is in subcategory or not.

The problem is that in my current function when i navigate to a product, the function returns me to the parent category, not in the sub.

```
- Category
  |-> Sub Category
     |-> Product
```

The function

```
function previous_next_product(){

    echo '<div class="prev_next_buttons">';

    // Get parent product categories on single product pages
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'include_children' => true ) );

    // Get the first main product category (not a child one)
    $term = reset($terms);
    $term_link =  get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ); // The link
    echo '<a href="'.$term_link.'"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

   // 'product_cat' will make sure to return next/prev from current category
   $previous = next_post_link('%link', '&larr;', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');
   $next = previous_post_link('%link', '&rarr;', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');

   echo $previous;
   echo $next;

   echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/) to get category object, and can easily extract `slug` or any other information needed.

**Here's example code:**

```
//load data of your child category
$child = get_category(CHILD_CATEGORY_ID_HERE);

//from your child category, load sub parent object
$sub_parent = get_category($child->parent);

//load parent from your sub parent
$parent = get_category($sub_parent->parent);

//extract slug like this
echo $sub_parent->slug; //will print slug of sub parent
```

And to check, if `category` has parent, you can use this:

```
if($child->parent){
   //extract subchild slug here
   //can do similar check for parent, if exists then extract parent object info
}
```

By using this code, you **can extract**:

1. Child
2. Sub Parent
3. Parent

Hope it helps! :)